# Spreadsheetgear .find method

Tags: asp.net, excel-2007, spreadsheetgear

Tools: asp.net VB, SpreadsheetGear 2010

I need to read in Excel files from external users and I do not control the format.  There are 3 sections of data.  I am able to read in the header.  The challenge is that the body details can contain an infinite number of rows, and sometimes those rows are blank. I can determine the footer row because there is a piece of text that is unique.  Therefore I can perform the following:

```
Dim dFoot As SpreadsheetGear.IRange = worksheet.Cells("20:21").Rows

Dim rngDet As SpreadsheetGear.IRange  

rngDet = dFoot.Find(what:="UNIQUE TEXT HERE", 
                    lookIn:=SpreadsheetGear.FindLookIn.Values, 
                    lookAt:=SpreadsheetGear.LookAt.Whole, 
                    searchOrder:=SpreadsheetGear.SearchOrder.ByColumns, 
                    searchDirection:=SpreadsheetGear.SearchDirection.Next, 
                    matchCase:=False, 
                    after:=dFoot)
```

Unfortunately, I am now stuck here.  I cannot determine where the cell is (i.e. V79) or how to move  7 columns over and 3 down to get the first value for inserting.  I have tried offset and different methods of reading the `rngDet`, but no luck.  I have also tried `rngDet.Activate()` to read the active cell, but it does not work the same as Microsoft.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I don't quite follow what what exactly you are trying to do.  For instance, what cell are you trying to find in relation to your 3 sections of data?  Are you trying to insert additional cells or rows at this point?  What is the significance of moving 7 columns over and 3 down?  Feel free to elaborate on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Tim,  Thank you for your questions.  First time asking so I probably was not very clear.  I did find the answer for myself today.  I have a group of cells that I need to upload.  The problem is that they will be moving up and down the page depending on how many rows were entered in the section above.  I realized that I did know what column it was going to be in so I performed the following:

```
Dim x As Integer
    Dim xFooter As Integer
    Dim columnnumber As Integer = 21 'Column V

    txtTest.Text = worksheet.Cells.RowCount
    For x = 500 To 1 Step -1

        If worksheet.Cells(x, columnnumber).Value = "TOTAL PRODUCT COST CALCULATION" Then
            txtTest.Text = x
            xFooter = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
```

I am now able to use my x value as the left hand corner of my group of cells.  I know that the values go over 7 columns from here and down 20 rows which gives me my quandrant of values.

Thought I would share just in case anyone has the same problem.